# How to hot-reload JSX in React apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, livereload

I have used the CRA or (create-react-app) a lot while starting react. The hot reloading of CSS changes work and are awesome. Whereas hot-reloading of JSX and class functions don't work - if I change JSX or some event handler - the page reloads.

Some threads pointed out that if I uncomment this line

```
//require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
```

in `webpack.config.dev.js` then it will work - but it still doesn't work

Neither does this webpack flag work in `package.json` `npm start script`:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --hot --config webpack.config.js"
```

--hot doesnt work.

Now I'm learning Redux - and one of it's features is hot reloading - so if I just learn Redux - will I be able to do it - or this is some config change or will I have to install some extra NPM package? Please guide.

Comment: Did you try adding --inline --hot ?

Comment: IMHO Redux is not related to hot reloading at all